# Trying to get property of non-object in Zend Framework 1.11 Application

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'm trying to create a table of information in a database query using Zend Framework 1.11, Zend_Db, and Zend_Db_Select.

Initially, I went about this by instantiating a new instance of my table and using $table->select().

However, when I went to JOIN it to another table, I got an error message that I wasn't able to JOIN using this select() method. After doing some research, I found that I had to call the select() method off of my default adapter if I wanted to do this JOIN. Seemed straightforward.

At this point, I have a model, a controller, and a view, but I think something is getting "lost in translation" between my Controller & my View.

Here is the model (inside Application_Model_DbTable_ActivityRequest):

```
public function getAllActivityRequests()
{

        $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter();
        $select = $db->select();

        $select->from('activityrequest');
        $select->where('isDeleted = ?','N');
        $select->where('ReqType <> ?','Purchase Product');
        $select->order('ReqTime DESC');

        $query = $select->query();
        $row = $query->fetchAll();

        return $row;
}
```

And the Controller (Admin Controller):

```
public function getWorkAction()
{

    $table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Activityrequest();

    $row = $table->getAllActivityRequests();

    $this->view->activityrequests = $row;

}
```

And (relevant part of)the View (admin/get-work):

```
<?php foreach($this->activityrequests as $activity): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $activity->CustomerID; ?></td>
    <td><?= $activity->ReqType; ?></td>
    <td><?= $activity->ReqTime; ?></td>
    <td><?= $activity->PickupTime; ?></td>
    <td><?= $activity->AddressID; ?></td>
    <td><?= $activity->Notes; ?></td>
    <td><?= $activity->HeardAbtUs; ?></td>
    <td><?= $activity->isDeleted; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I do a var_dump of $row in both my model and my controller, I see the array that I'm trying to pass to the view. As soon as I get to the view, though, I get this error on a "non-object."

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual error message in full?

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/Mamp/htdocs/fifthroomstorage.com/application/views/scripts/admin/get-work.phtml on line 14

Comment: I think I need to figure out a way to make the array an object. Or at least each row an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your adapter / select / dbTable fetch mode.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetch-mode

Alternatively, use the `Zend_Db_Table` to full advantage

```
public function getAllActivityRequests()
{
    return $this->fetchAll(
        $this->select()
            ->where('isDeleted = ?', 'N')
            ->where('ReqType <> ?', 'Purchase Product')
            ->order('ReqTime DESC')
    );
}
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.fetch-all.select